# A React, Vue, or other code depends on an object, not yet available. The best ways to wait for that variable, before rendering component content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, variables, window

When an HTML document defined a variable that is not available until a later time during the page load.

Issue: A React, Vue, or other block of code depends on an object that has not yet been declared and outside the direct scope of the component, like window['varname']. What are the proper way(s) to wait for that variable to be defined before rendering a component's real content.

**My Attempt:**

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import AppWrapper from "./components/AppWrapper";

const App = () => {
  let intervalId
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('Waking up... checking if window.app is defined')
    if (window['app'] !== undefined) {
      console.log('yes')
      clearInterval(intervalId)
    } else {
      console.log('no')
    }
  }, 1000)

  if(app.ins.length === 0) {
    return 'Loading...'
  }

  return (
      <AppWrapper app={window['app']}></AppWrapper>
  )
}

export default App
```

What other ways could you, should you, do it?

I will make it clearer for you :) I will describe exactly my problem: So I am writing a custom Joomla Component for Joomla. The Joomla Component is written in PHP and uses the Joomla Framework. Inside this component, I have written a Reactjs component. The way that you inject JavaScript into Joomla is via Joomla Methods. These methods either load the JS on the head of the document or in the body. Now, my Reactjs component is loaded during this process. This is fine and it works as long as I do not need to rely on outside variables.

I am using Joomla to store data that is need by the Reactjs component. The way that Joomla makes data available to JS is by a Joomla library that will inject the JS object into a script tag. This is also okay. The issue is that when the head tag loads the Reactjs component before the injected JS object, needed by the Reactjs component, is available. In my example above I store the global JS object into the window object as window.app = Some Object. Because the window.app object is not available at the time the Reactjs component has been loaded, I add a setInterval and check every 500 ms.

Then the setInterval wakes up and checks to see if the window["app"] is available yet. It keeps doing that until it is available. Once it is, it quits the interval and loads the Reactjs component container, passing in the required object.

### Now, two things here:

1. I have no way of synchronizing this process in Joomla. Joomla is stubborn like that.
2. This is my attempted to only load the Reactjs container component once the data is available.

### Question: Knowing the situation, what are the best strategies to accomplish this, apart from my current strategy?

Thanks :)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  In terms of React, are you just looking for the concept of "state" (which is fundamental to the framework and demonstrated in any/every tutorial)?  In this case that `window['app']` value should probably be in state, not a global variable.  But if, for some reason, it *must* be a global variable then in your interval you could make some innocuous state update to trigger a re-render when the value is available.

Comment: Along with the concept of state, you have to make sure whatever is triggering your isLoading state is reactive.

Comment: in Vue you would simply use the [v-if](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html) directive on a component that needs to wait on some data to load before rendering

Comment: No I am not asking that. I will make it clearer for you :)

I will describe exactly my problem:

So I am writing a custom Joomla Component for Joomla. The Joomla Component is written in PHP and uses the Joomla Framework. Inside this component, I have written a Reactjs component. The way that you inject JavaScript into Joomla is via Joomla Methods. These methods either load the JS on the head of the document or in the body. Now, my Reactjs component is loaded during this process. This is fine and it works as long as I do not need to rely on outside variables. Continue in next comment....

Comment: I am using Joomla to store data that is need by the Reactjs component. The way that Joomla makes data available to JS is by a Joomla library that will inject the JS object into a script tag. This is also okay. The issue is that when the head tag loads the Reactjs component before the injected JS object, needed by the Reactjs component, is available. In my example above I store the global JS object into the window object as window.app = Some Object. Because the window.app object is not available at the time the Reactjs component has been loaded, I add a setInterval and check every 500 ms...

Comment: Then the setInterval wakes up and checks to see if the window["app"] is available yet. It keeps doing that until it is available. Once it is, it quits the interval and loads the Reactjs component container, passing in the required object. 

Now, two things here:
1. I have no way of synchronising this process in Joomla. Joomla is stubborn like that.
2. This is my attempted to only load the Reactjs container component once the data is available.

## Question: Knowing the situation, what are the best strategies to accomplish this, apart from my current strategy?

Thanks :)

Comment: * I have added these comments to the original question above. In a few days I will remove these comments in lieu of the update to the original content above *

Answer (score 0):

I believe, one of the approaches could be any kind of callback or subscription.

For example, you can define a function, which changes a state in state-container like `redux`.
(Pseudocode)

```
async function loadAppData(store) {
  const data = await fetch('/some-data');
  const json = await data.json();
  store.dispatch('data-loaded', json)
}
```

And in component

```
function App() {
  const appData = useSelector(store => store.appData);
  if (!appData) {
    return 'Loading...'
  }
  return <Markup />
}
```

Other option can be subscription. Again you can add some function which emits some event:

```
async function loadAppData(store) {
  const data = await fetch('/some-data');
  const json = await data.json();
  eventBus.emit('data-loaded', json)
  // or
  window.appData = json
}
```

In react you can

```
function App() {
  const [appData, setAppData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setAppData(window.appData)
  }, [window.appData])

  if (!appData) {
    return 'Loading...'
  }
  return <Markup />
}
```

Or in Vue.js you could

```
data() {
  return {
    appData: ''
  }
}

mounted() {
  this.$on('data-loaded', this.onDataLoaded)
}

methods: {
  onDataLoaded($event) {
   this.appData = $event;
  }
}
```